# Setting up Arq to use Google Cloud Storage without giving it your login credentials and all storage access

Tags: backup, storage, authentication

Is it possible to setup Arq backup to use Google Cloud Storage without having to give it your login credentials

I'd like to use Arq to backup my computer with Google Cloud Storage. When I try to set this up it asks for my account name/password

[image: add google cloud storage account]

[image: name/pass]

It then asks for permission to control all storage in my account

[image: control my storage]

It doesn't seem like good practice to be giving some 3rd party app control of my google account.

[Google Cloud Storage has ways to make keys for apps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) which seems like a more correct way to set up something like Arq. That way I could make a key that only has permission to access a single pre-created storage object and give that key to Arq. I never have to type my password into Arq and if someone manages to steal my key they only have access to that one object. Also I don't have to worry that Arq is going to accidentally access or delete any storage objects that don't belong to it.

Is there a way to do that?

Otherwise it seems my only other option is to make a separate Google account just for Arq?

Answer (score 2):

You can give another Google account access to, for example, a single bucket in your Google Cloud account. Then use that other Google account in Arq, and Arq will only have access to that 1 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how OAuth 2.0 authentication works.

You don't store the user name and password in Arq, nor give it control over your Google account, but authenticate the app directly to Google API.

You give Arq only the specified permissions for logging on and the Google Cloud Storage, as indicated on the screenshot you attached.

The screenshots you see are not Arq's forms, but a browser session directly to Google which will return the access token to Arq.

---

You are considering point 4.4.1.4 of [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819): "Maliciuos Client Obtains Authorization". It lists what precautions shall be taken on the server side.

On the client side, if you are considering Arq a malicious application, you shouldn't be running it in the first place.

---

If you are concerned about a keylogger (that's what you imply by some program remembering your password) then you should use 2-nd Factor Authentication with your Google account.

Comment: I don't have to consider Arq malicious to not trust it. As far as I know some other app can steal their cached permissions and then use my account. Some library they use might be doing something bad. They might have a bug that leaks the authentication .Therefore it's ridiculous to give any app more permissions that in it absolutely needs. Giving it access to **all** storage is way more than it needs.

Comment: @gman So what is incorrect in my answer? How can I improve it? Does the application get user credentials or not? As for your rant about requirements, shouldn't you send your concerns to the author of the software instead of commenting here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion to grant another Google account access to the storage bucket, you will also have to grant that account 'viewer' access to your overall project. If you don't Arq will freeze when attempting to access the project.